# Special case of standard deviation

Tags: statistics

I am interested in finding how much a set of values are varying from a set of reference values. I have two sets, S1 and Ref. Ref has reference values mapped one-to-one to elements of S1.

```
S1 = { 1,5,4,8,2,1,4,6}
Ref = { 1,2,5,4,5,6,4,2}
```

Variance for S1 would be mean of squared differences from the mean. which is 5.36. 
And standard deviation is square-root of the variance, 2.31.

Variance and standard deviation are calculated around the mean of S1. I am planning to use each element of Ref instead of mean of S1 to find the variance and standard deviation (Well i can use different terms for them if needed by definitions). 
$$Var = \sum_{i=0}^{N}\frac{(S1_i-Ref_i)^2}{N}$$
$$SD= \sqrt{Var}$$
Is this a correct way of finding how much S1 deviates from Ref element-wise? Is there already another metric to do this in a standard way?

PS: Apologies, Statistics is new to me :)

Comment: You could try a goodness of fit test, for example, the Chi-squared test between the two data.

Comment: Well...it would seem to put a lot of weight on the ordering.  If, say, Ref was a permutation of $S1$ then you'd get something non-$0$, but would you really say that the two sets were unequal?

Comment: @lulu , Ordering is a fixed one-to-one mapping. My experiment ensures that. For each element of S1, there is a reference value.  I need to find how much does the S1 deviate from Ref (either element-wise or overall)

Comment: Well, if you have two time series, $X,Y$, it certainly makes sense to study the statistics of their difference.  In that case, you'd be lead to consider the sum $\frac 1N\times \sum (X_i-Y_i-\overline {(X+Y)}$.  What you wrote isn't a variance because you don't adjust for the mean.

Comment: The sum that you defined signifies how much X and Y vary from each other and is corrected for their mean? Is there a standard term for such a sum?